# What Jersey security annotation can be used to permit anonymous only access to an endpoint?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I have a registration endpoint that I only want anonymous users to be able to access. In other words, I only want non-authenticated users to be able to POST to the endpoint. What is the best way to go about doing this?

```
@Path("/accounts")
public class AccountResource {

    @Inject
    private AccountService accountService;

    @DenyAll
    @POST
    public void register(CreateAccountJson account) {
        try {
            accountService.registerUserAndCreateAccount(account.getEmail(),
                account.getPassword());
        } catch (RegistrationException e) {
            throw new BadRequestException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such annotation. This use case doesn't really fit into the semantics of authorization. One work around you can use is to inject the `SecurityContext`. Just check if there is a `Principal`. If not, then there is no authenticated user. If there is, then you could just send a 404

```
@POST
public void register(@Context SecurityContext context, CreateAccountJson account) {

    if (context.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    ...
}
```

#### UPDATE

If you have a lot of resource methods like this, it might be better to use a filter that is name bound. For example

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NonAuthenticated {}

@NonAuthenticated
// Perform before normal authorization filter
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION - 1)
public class NonAuthenticatedCheckFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) {
        final SerurityContext context = request.getSecurityContext();
        if (context.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }
    }
}

@POST
@NonAuthenticated
public void register(CreateAccountJson account) { }

// register the Dw
environment.jersey().register(NonAuthenticatedCheckFilter.class);
```

For more information on Jersey filters see [Filter and Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#filters-and-interceptors) from Jersey docs.